# Adding multiple authors to an ArrayList from user input

Tags: java, arraylist, input

I have two classes and they both form ArrayLists. I have a menu option where the user needs to be able to add a book (title, copyright, ISBN, edition, and AUTHOR). This works entirely, but the problem is I need an option to add multiple authors and I cannot think of a way around this. Here is my working code below for adding a single author:

```
public void addBook(ArrayList<Book> books, ArrayList<Author> aut) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the title:");
    String title = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the copyright:");
    int copy = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the edition:");
    int ed = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the isbn:");
    String isbn = scan.nextLine();
    scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter the author: ");
    String authors = scan.nextLine();

    ArrayList<Author> aut = new ArrayList<>();
    String firstName = authors.split(" ")[0];
    String lastName = authors.split(" ")[1];
    Author bookAuthor = new Author(firstName, lastName);
    boolean foundAuthor = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < aut.size(); i++) {
        Author currentAuthor = aut.get(i);
        if (currentAuthor.getFirst().equalsIgnoreCase(firstName)
                && currentAuthor.getLast().equalsIgnoreCase(lastName)) {
            bookAuthor = currentAuthor;
            foundAuthor = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!foundAuthor) {
        aut.add(bookAuthor);
    }
    au.add(bookAuthor);
    books.add(new Book(title, copy, ed, isbn, au));

}
```

What is best approach to support the user entering multiple authors?

Comment: Multiple authors for each book, or multiple books _and_ authors?

Comment: You're supposed to be able to add only single books at a time, but with the option for multiple authors. It isn't visible in the code I posted, but when this method finishes, it brings the user back to the menu where they can repeatedly select add a book. They would have to do that to add an additional book. Does that make sense?

Comment: Create a method that ask the user for the authors that returns the `ArrayList<Author>` that you add to the book.  So you can move all the author code here into that method, then put an extra loop around it that repeats the question in the new method with a new question like `Would you like to add another author?`.  Call that code here one time and set it to the `au`.  If you are still confused I can whip up an example.

Comment: It is pretty hard to understand the intent of this code at a glance, and therefore the question. If you are trying to take a dynamic number of inputs, try a `while` loop in conjunction with your `Scanner` logic. If the `Book` class can't handle multiple `Authors`, we'd need to see `Book`'s definition to know where you went wrong. :)

Comment: I think the list of authors should actually be a member of the book class along with the logic for adding a new author. That would make things a lot less convoluted in the main class.

Comment: Just a suggestion on the readability of your code: `addBook` seems to do a lot more than add a book, and variable names like `aut`, `au`, `bookAuthor`, and `authors` in the same block is really confusing. Additionally, splitting out some of this logic into separate methods would be really helpful for whoever will read this code. The `Scanner` logic especially could be completely extracted away from the `Author`/`Book` logic and into its own method (or vice versa).

Comment: @Anil M It looks like the `List` of authors already is a member in the `Book` class because it uses the `List` of `au` in the `new Book` constructor at the bottom.

Comment: Here is the constructor of my Book class--does that help?

public Book(String title, int copyright, int edition, String isbn, ArrayList<Author> authors) {
  super();
  this.title = title;
  this.copyright = copyright;
  this.edition = edition;
  this.isbn = isbn;
  this.authors = authors;

Comment: Yeah it seems like you've done all of the work and just need to work the input logic into a loop, yeah?

Comment: @arcadeblast77 and Anil M I know it's very convoluted, but I have to follow the UML my teacher gave me. This is in no way how I would go about this given my own freedom, but I have to make it work.

Comment: Yes, the loop is really what I am struggling with at this point. Not sure if i've just looked at it too long and can't see the forest for the trees or what

Comment: How do you want the user to indicate they are done entering authors? You want them to enter them separately on each line right?

Comment: @arcadeblast77 when I had attempted this originally, I changed the line to read "Please enter author. For multiple authors, please separate with a /" so I could use it as a delimiter. When I was tooling around with using a while loop, I had theperson enter an author and then be prompted "are you done entering authors, y/n", but there aren't any restrictions of HOW to ask.

Comment: I would consider coming up with a special string that the user can input to exit the "enter-authors" loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fairly long, but hopefully this should help you.

First off, you should put a method in your `Book` class, that will prompt a user for authors, and add any of entered authors into the `list` for that object.

Here is what that class would look like along with a `main` that is just for testing purposes.  I have excluded all of your other fields:

```
public class Book {

    ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<>();

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(String title, int copyright, int edition, String isbn, ArrayList<Author> authors) { 
        /* 
          I left these fields out of this example on purpose.
        this.title = title; 
        this.copyright = copyright; 
        this.edition = edition; 
        this.isbn = isbn; */
        this.authors = authors; 
    }

    public void promptForAuthors()
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String response = "Y";

        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter the author. ");
            String input = scan.nextLine();
            String [] splitAuthors = input.split(" ");

            Author author = new Author(splitAuthors[0], splitAuthors[1]);

            if (!this.authors.contains(author)) {
                this.authors.add(author);
            }

            System.out.println("Would you like you add an additional author? (Y or N) ");
            response = scan.nextLine();

        } while(response.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
    }

    public void printAuthors() {
        for (Author a : this.authors) {
            System.out.println(a.getFirstName() + " " + a.getLastName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book b = new Book(); //This will normally be the constructor that includes the ISBN, copyright, etc.
        b.promptForAuthors();
        b.printAuthors();
    }
}
```

You can see from the `main` how you should use this in your `addBooks` code.  Basically you create your `Book` out of all the other fields you used as input, then you can call this method on that object.

You will probably need to modify your current constructor so that it no longer requires the `list` for authors to be input when constructed, so you can use it afterward (you can just have both constructors available as well).

The `promptForAuthors()` will continue to prompt the user to enter in an `Author` until they hit anything other than `Y` or `y`.

This method will always ask for an author as least a single time, due to the use of a `do-while` loop.  One of the main advantages of doing it in the `Book` class itself, is this method could be reused at any time to add more authors to the same book down the line if that is functionality eventually needed.

Additionally, the method will use `.contains()` to check if the `Author` already exists inside of the `list`, and only add the `Author` if it is a new `Author`.  This requires an `Override` of `.hashCode()` and `.equals()` in your `Author` class which you can find the one I made below:

```
//IN THE AUTHOR CLASS PLACE THESE METHODS AND MODIFY FOR EXTRA FIELDS
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Author)) {
        return false;
    }

    Author user = (Author) o;

    return user.firstName.equals(this.firstName) &&
           user.lastName.equals(this.lastName);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = 17;
    result = 31 * result + this.firstName.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + this.lastName.hashCode();
    return result;
}
```

**Note:**  I included a `printAuthors()` method just as an easy way to verify no extra duplicate `Authors` were added.

**Example Run of adding Authors:**

```
Please enter the author. 
Joe Smith
Would you like you add an additional author? (Y or N) 
y
Please enter the author. 
Billy Bob
Would you like you add an additional author? (Y or N) 
n
Joe Smith
Billy Bob
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try allowing the user to enter a special string to exit the input loop.**

Change

```java
String authors = scan.nextLine();
```

into a loop to populate a list of strings from input

```java
ArrayList<String> authorNames = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println("Please enter authors. Enter DONE when you are done.");
String nextLine = scan.nextLine();
while (!nextLine.equals("DONE")) {
  authorNames.add(nextLine);
  nextLine = scan.nextLine();
}
// This doesn't prevent the user from entering zero authors. Idk if you care about that.
```

alternatively, accept input of authors as only ***one*** line with some delimiter and use `String.split` on that delimiter later.

Answer (score 0):

1 - create a list of lists.(List of Another list author).

2 - create an object of author list.

3 - perform all the action you want to perform on this author list.

4 - add author list to list of author list.

5 - To access author you need syntax like first_list_object.get(index).author_object_variable_or_member.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Author>> authorList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Author> au = new ArrayList<Author>();
String firstName = authors.split(" ")[0];
String lastName = authors.split(" ")[1];
Author bookAuthor = new Author(firstName, lastName);
au.add(bookAuthor);
authorList.add(au);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You're working with the wrong collection. You have a couple of author's. Each author could have written several books. So the right thing would be a `Map<Author,ArrayList<Book>>`.
It will make Your programming logic for `addBook()` easier, if You can use a map.